# jmockit how to disable only static block and not static variables

Tags: jmockit

Team,

We are working on on use case where we want to mock only static block and not the static 
variables inside the class

e.g.

```
 public class BusinessClassOne
 {  
   public static final BusinessClassTwo businessTwo = new BusinessClassTwo();

   static
   {
    Initalize the services here

   }


 }
```

Question is how do we mock only static block and initialize static variable normally in jmockit.

We tried below and it seems it is not initalizing businessTwo **static final** variable.

Note this is legacy code and we donot want to change it.

```
@Before
 public void staticInitializers()
 {

 new MockUp<BusinessClassOne>() {
      @Mock
      void $clinit()
      {
          System.out.println("Static is bypassed");
      }
   };

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that a `static` field is initialized separately from the execution of a `static` block, when in fact the Java compiler puts *all* the bytecode for class initialization into a *single* "method" of signature `void <clinit>()`.

Comment: Understand that but is there any way to achieve this behaviour mock only static block and not static variables within the class.

Comment: by doing some hack or some otherway for this scenario

Comment: The usual approach is to mock the dependency, not the static initializer of the dependent class. That is, you would mock `BusinessClassTwo` in this example.